# Rails server gives error when I load localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server

So, I have started learning ruby on rails, I used following command to create a ROR project:

```
rails new blog
```

next I write following command to run the rails server:

```
rails s
```

The Rails server runs, and I load `localhost:3000` in a web browser; but I get `500 internal error` on the web browser.

The log file has following error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:338:in `parse_query'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/request.rb:191:in `GET'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:300:in `GET'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:14:in `parameters'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/filter_parameters.rb:37:in `filtered_parameters'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:22:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.1.3) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /home/shrakuma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/shrakuma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/shrakuma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /home/shrakuma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (3.6ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-18 12:59:57 -0700

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:338:in `parse_query'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/request.rb:191:in `GET'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:300:in `GET'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:14:in `parameters'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/filter_parameters.rb:37:in `filtered_parameters'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:22:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.1.3) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /home/shrakuma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/shrakuma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/shrakuma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Looks like this issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20624

Comment: That rails issue matches my current issue as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the new Rack Gem version 1.6.3.
For now, try to lock down the version of rack in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack', '1.6.2'
```

run `bundle update rack` afterwards.

Relevant issue:

https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/896

**Update**

Meanwhile, version 1.6.4 was released. That should do, too.
https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/896#issuecomment-113299792

Comment: Editing the rack version in gemlock file made the trick, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Our quick fix to the Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack', '1.6.1'
```

This should unblock you for now until https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20624 is resolved.

Comment: The breaking change was added in rack 1.6.3, so 1.6.2 should be fine.

Comment: changing rack version to 1.6.1 worked thanks...