# Rails 'parse_query' error on server in brand new app

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, osx-yosemite, rbenv

I have installed on OS X 10.10.3:
homebrew, command line tools, then installed ruby using rbenv:

```
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin14]
Rails 4.2.2
```

when I create a new app (with default sqlite database) and try to run it, it says:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-06-18 23:11:30] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-06-18 23:11:30] INFO  ruby 2.2.2 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-darwin14]
[2015-06-18 23:11:30] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=41860 port=3000
```

but in the browser I see:

```
500 Internal Server Error
If you are the administrator of this website, then please read this web application's log file and/or the web server's log file to find out what went wrong.
```

log file:

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-06-18 23:11:48 +0300

**ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):**
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:338:in `parse_query'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/request.rb:191:in `GET'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:300:in `GET'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:14:in `parameters'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/filter_parameters.rb:37:in `filtered_parameters'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:22:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.1.3) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /Users/smi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/smi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/smi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/smi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (22.3ms)
```

Somebody has a similar error? how did you resolve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924833/rails-server-gives-error-when-i-load-localhost3000

Comment: I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Wow, just encountered this problem and you already asked it for me "3 hours ago." The internet is amazing.

Comment: I edited the title since this question is being linked by a bunch of duplicates and the issue is not really OSX related at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was getting the same thing, but with Rails 4.2.1, and running on Puma 2.11.3.

I noticed that Bundler just upgraded rack to 1.6.3.  Setting the version back to 1.6.2 resolved it for me.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20624

To solve it, change in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack', '1.6.1'
```

Comment: Using version 1.6.1 of rack isn't recommended as it is affected by [CVE-2015-3225](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rubyonrails-security/gcUbICUmKMc/qiCotVZwXrMJ) (potential denial of service vulnerability). Use version 1.6.2 or 1.6.4.