# New ( clean ) Rails project crash ( Action pack error )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crash, actionpack

I have just created a rails project :
rails new project -d mysql

et modify the database.rb to match and when I try rails s -b 0.0.0.0 end access to local.dev:3000 ( vagrant machine ) I have an issue.

```
Started GET "/" for 192.168.56.1 at 2015-06-18 21:25:47 +0000
Cannot render console from 192.168.56.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:338:in `parse_query'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/request.rb:191:in `GET'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:300:in `GET'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:14:in `parameters'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/filter_parameters.rb:37:in `filtered_parameters'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:22:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.1.3) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:29:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Thank You for your help

Comment: Try `bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0`

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925008/just-installed-rails-on-yosemite-and-rails-server-fails

Comment: tldr looks like a bad version of `rack` went out today.

Answer (score 0):

In you Gemfile.lock find rack (1.6.3) and change it back to rack (1.6.2) make sure you bundle afterwards.

Comment: Rack is 1.6.4 and I can't change it , it isn't in the Gemfile